# A background image does not display as part of the div container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div container. I need to use a transparent picture as a background, include a separate picture in the div and some text. I am doind the following:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('explore_block.png');
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="icon">
  <p>This paragraph has its own background color.</p>
</div>
```

The filepath is correct, however the picture does not appear.
Could you provide any help? Thank you!:)

Comment: remove the `'` first and try if not remove `-img` also

Comment: what? you edited post 27 mins ago and @sutemeny Andras answered 24 mins ago.. but your code works fine..no error.. why you accepted his answer..??

Comment: What I am supposed to do?

Comment: nothing i'm just saying it.. there is nothing to correct in your html.. just make sure that you've given right image path.. that's it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You left a double colon, after the background-image. ;)
It works now.

```
  <head>
  <style>
  div {
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
      background-image: url('explore_block.png');
  }
  </style>
  </head>


 <body>
 <div> 
 <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="icon">
 <p>This paragraph has its own background color.</p>
 </div>
 </body>


 </html>
```

Comment: what? @Vanina Yordanova edited post 27 mins ago and you answered 24 mins ago.. but Vanina Yordanova code works fine.. nothing to correct.. he accepted your answer mate!! lol :O :(

Comment: Question is the answer ! lol :'(

Comment: :) yeah. you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one, could you try using

```
background-size: cover
```

See how that goes, it's hard to see without a visual representation :)

Answer (score 1):

Ger rid of `'` inside `url` also `-img`

```
 div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(explore_block.png);
}
```

Working fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/9acajpkk/2/

Comment: with/without (apostrophe) ' ' also it works.. don't you know that??

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following CSS to your div.

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("explore_block.png");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="icon">
  <p>This paragraph has its own background color.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your html and css works fine.. give right image path and check once again.

with/without (apostrophe) `' '` also it works..

Working Jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/koh7dx5z/1/

Comment: Read question he did in `css`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/koh7dx5z/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this: 
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('backgroundimg.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="icon">
  <p>This paragraph has its own background color.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```